# Let's arrange a J.SE chabura

Tags: discussion, chat

After Sukkos we could arrange a J.SE chabura.

We could pick a subject, maarei mkomos, and discuss the sugya in a chat room.

This may also help in getting more experts to the site.

Comment: Just a thought - timing might be killer, especially considering the wide range of geographic locations.

Comment: @WAF that is the advantage of chat. Although there seems to be times when a few people are there at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, timing might well be a killer. Also to be determined is level.

Comment: The best way to find out how feasible this idea is and how to work out some of the details is probably to do a test run. I'd recommend that you set whatever time is convenient to you (say, for an hour duration) but encourage ongoing asynchronous chat for the next day or so, and that you present it at whatever level makes sense to you, then see how those choices work out. This is the sort of thing that could be iterated many times by many people with different parameters, at low cost.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, re "ongoing asynchronous chat for the next day or so": Good idea. It might even lead to another confluence of chatters, which would be a _chabura tachas chabura_.

Comment: So, Shmuel, are you going to try it?

Comment: **NOTE:** Something similar has been implemented as [the Parashat Hashavua' Chat](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/520).

Answer (score 3):

I'm keen. Please let me know if you go ahead.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/520.